# Second y axis on D3 column chart

Tags: javascript, css, json, d3.js

I have a chart created with the code below. I want to add a second y axis positioned to the right which matches the same y scale. The reason I want the y axis on the right also is because of the limit line I have set at 16.5, the chart just doesn’t look right without the 2nd y axis.

```
<script>
var w = 800;
var h = 550;
var margin = {
    top: 58,
    bottom: 100,
    left: 80,
    right: 40
    };
var width = w - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var threshold = 16.5;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(data.map(function(entry){
    return entry.key;
}))
    .rangeBands([0, width],.2);
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
    return d.value;
})])
    .range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()   
              .scale(x)
              .orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(y)
              .orient("left");                        
var yGridLines = d3.svg.axis()
                     .scale(y)
                     .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
                     .tickFormat("")
                     .orient("left");
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("id", "chart")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);
var chart = svg.append("g")
    .classed("display", true)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

function plot(params){
this.append("g")
     .call(yGridLines)
     .classed("gridline", true)
     .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
this.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(params.data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .classed("bar", true)
    .attr("x", function (d,i){
        return x(d.key);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d,i){
        return y(d.value);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d,i){
        return height - y(d.value);
    })
    .attr("width", function(d){
        return x.rangeBand();
    });
this.selectAll(".bar-label")
    .data(params.data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .classed("bar-label", true)
    .attr("x", function(d,i){
        return x(d.key) + (x.rangeBand()/2)
    })
    .attr("dx", 0)
    .attr("y", function(d,i){
        return y(d.value);
    })
    .attr("dy", -6)
    .text(function(d){
        return d.value;
    })
this.append("g")
 .classed("x axis", true)
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + height + ")")
 .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", -8)
            .attr("dy" ,8)
            .attr("transform", "translate(0,0) rotate(-45)");

this.append("g")
     .classed("y axis", true)
     .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
     .call(yAxis);
this.select(".y.axis")
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-50," + height/2 + ") rotate(-90)")
    .text("Downtime [Hrs]");

this.select(".x.axis")
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + ",80)")
    .text("[Stations]");    
    // title 
this.append("text")
    .attr("x", (width / 2))             
    .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
    .style("font-size", "16px") 
    .style("text-decoration", "underline")  
    .text("Over Mould");  
    // limit line 
this.append("line")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", y(threshold))
    .attr("x2", width)
    .attr("y2", y(threshold))
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
     .attr("stroke", "yellow");
}
d3.json('data.json', function(data) {

plot.call(chart, {data: data});
});
</script>
```

Data is coming from an external JSON file.

```
[
{
    "key": "ING_SW_CB",
    "value": "7"
},
{
    "key": "SB_SW_CB",
    "value": "15"
},
{
    "key": "NG3_SW_CB",
    "value": "3"
},
{
    "key": "Mould_Close",
    "value": "8"
},
{
    "key": "Leak_Test",
    "value": "9"
},
{
    "key": "ML_Load",
    "value": "2"
},
{
    "key": "Pre_Heat",
    "value": "1"
},
{
    "key": "Dispense",
    "value": "5"
},
{
    "key": "A310",
    "value": "6"
},
{
    "key": "Gelation",
    "value": "5"
},
{
    "key": "Platen",
    "value": "7"
},
{
    "key": "Mainline_Unload",
    "value": "8"
},
{
    "key": "De_mould",
    "value": "5"
},
{
    "key": "Clean_Up",
    "value": "4"
},
{
    "key": "Soda_Blast",
    "value": "5"
},
{
    "key": "RMI",
    "value": "15"
},
{
    "key": "Miscellaneous",
    "value": "5"
}
]
```

My idea was to create yAxis2 and call it later in the function that plots the chart.

```
var yAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(y)
              .orient("right");

this.append("g")
    .classed("y axis", true)
    .attr("transform", "translate(width,0)")
    .call(yAxis2);
```

When I do this it just draws it in the same place as the first yAxis, when I adjust the transform/ translate it just gets drawn at random positions on the chart, I'm trying to line it up like the left yAxis only positioned on the right. Thanks to all for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error:

```
.attr("transform", "translate(width,0)")
```

To:

```
.attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LbZ1YApNen7OjiMfHzCU?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you Huan! that was driving me crazy. Job done , thanks again.

Comment: Here is a similar question: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609929/how-to-display-second-y-axis-to-right-of-grouped-bar-chart-data-in-d3)